# Editar tabela com valor correspondente <select>

Tags: php, html, sql

Tenho um formulário para editar os dados da tabela, está funcionando normalmente. Porém ao carregar a pagina está buscando o último nome da tabela.

Gostaria de saber um jeito de quando carregar a página, já venha selecionado o valor correspondente ao dado daquela tabela.

As relações estão certas, o insert, o delete e até o update. Porem quando vou editar, ao invés de buscar o nome do cargo correspondente ao funcionário ele busca o ultimo cargo. Veja:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer o if mas não deu muito certo...

Adicionei ao codigo a condição, se o cargo_id (Tabela Funcionario) for  igual a id_cargo (Tabela Cargo)

```
<?php if( $linha['cargo_id'] == $lista['id_cargo']){?>selected<?php } ?>
```

Fiz assim:

```
<select class="form-control" name="cargo_id">
    <?php 
    while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta_cargo,$consulta_func)){
      ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $lista['id_cargo']?>" <?php if( $linha['cargo_id'] == $lista['id_cargo']){?>selected<?php } ?>> <?php echo $lista['nome_cargo']?></option>
        <?php
    }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Coloque: `<option><?php echo $lista['nome_cargo']." - ".$linha['cargo_id']."/".$lista['id_cargo']?></option>` e veja se o option que deveria estar selecionado mostra os valores `$linha['cargo_id']` e `$lista['id_cargo']` iguais. Por exemplo: `Financeiro - 12/12` (supondo que o id do "Financeiro" seja "12").

Comment: Apesar de que é estranho, pq se o `if` tivesse falhando, o primeiro option é que deveria aparecer selecionado. Veja no código-fonte se os options aparecem `selected`. Se todos os options tiverem `selected`, o último será selecionado.

Comment: <option><?php echo $lista['nome_cargo']." - ".$linha['cargo_id']."/".$lista['id_cargo']?></option> não mostrou nada tambem...